# Making a custom JSON from provided data python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

data given:   `[british_museum.religion.mesopotamia]`

I have separated each of the categories in the data above by splitting it on the basis of full stop. Now I want to make a JSON object that displays the following

```
{ "categories" : 
          {"category": "british_museum",
           "category": "religion",
           "category": "mesopotamia"
          }
}
```

Now the problem is that the data given can be of any length i.e. there can be varied amount of categories in the data given. What could be a generic solution to attaining a JSON object for any data that is provided?
the condition is that the JSON format specified should be followed. If there are 5 categories, than there should be 5 "category" keys inside the "categories" key.

Comment: There can't exist such dictionary like `{"category": "british_museum", "category": "religion", "category": "mesopotamia"}`. Keys must be unique.

Comment: JSON should not contain duplicate keys.

Comment: You might use like this {"category1":"british_museum","category2":"religion","category3":"mesopotamia"}

Comment: or this `{ "categories" : ["british_museum", "religion", "mesopotamia" ] }`

Comment: Why not just a list (JSON array)?

Comment: I want to store this JSON into MongoDB. Wont it be difficult to query if keys are unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above comments @Craicerjack suggested better solution for this question.

I just converted it into code. You can save it to MongoDB.

```
>>> input_string = 'british_museum.religion.mesopotamia'
>>> splitted_values = input_string.split('.')
>>> output={}
>>> output['categories'] = splitted_values
>>> json.dumps(output)
```

Output:

```
{
  "categories": [
    "british_museum",
    "religion",
    "mesopotamia"
  ]
}
```

Comment: how can we query and check all categories in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries ***won't allow duplicate keys*** hence either you can split the text and append it as a list or you can create json with keyss like `"category1","category2",.....`

```
import json
data= ["british_museum.religion.mesopotamia"
,"british_museum.religion.mesopotamia1"]
json_data=[]
for word in data:
    json_data.append({"categories": {"category"+str(i): j for i,j in enumerate(word.split("."))}})
json.dumps(json_data)
```

**Result:**

```
[  
    {  
        "categories":{  
            "category1":"religion",
            "category0":"british_museum",
            "category2":"mesopotamia"
        }
    },
    {  
        "categories":{  
            "category1":"religion",
            "category0":"british_museum",
            "category2":"mesopotamia1"
        }
    }
]
```

or if you are ok with adding categories as list

```
import json
data= ["british_museum.religion.mesopotamia"
,"british_museum.religion.mesopotamia1"]
json_data=[]
for word in data:
    json_data.append({"categories":word.split(".")})
json.dumps(json_data)
```

**Result:**

```
[  
    {  
        "categories":[  
            "british_museum",
            "religion",
            "mesopotamia"
        ]
    },
    {  
        "categories":[  
            "british_museum",
            "religion",
            "mesopotamia1"
        ]
    }
]
```